# Write a function that accepts a character and returns true if it is a punctuation character, false otherwise.f this function: Use a RegExp

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

This is what I have so far. I know listing the characters like that doesn't work in the console. But I'm not sure how I can add them as a proper variable. And unlike other examples I've seen on here, it has to only except characters.

```js
var punc = "; : . , ? ! - '' "" () {}"
function isPunct(param) {
    if(punc.test(param)) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Well are you trying to use Java or Javascript? They're different languages. Please remove whichever tag is irrelevant. (This certainly looks like Javascript rather than Java...)

Comment: This is not a site called 'We do your homework', and the description of what problem you have with your function is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to list the specific punctuation you wish to check for as an array and then use the ES6 `Array.includes` method to compare.

```
const punc = [';', ':', '.', ',', '?', '!', '-', "'", '"', '(', ')', '{', '}']
const isPunc = character => punc.includes(character)

console.log(isPunc('!'))
// true

console.log(isPunc("x"))
// false
```